# productAttributeOptionManagementInterface api not loading attributes

Tags: product-attribute, api, eav, eav-attributes, magento2.3.5

I use `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface` in my constructor and since Magento 2.3.5 it doesn't load any attributes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface  implement three methods check below

**1. getItems**

**2. add**

**3. delete**

1) Retrieve the list of attribute options using.

```
public function getItems($attributeCode);
```

2) Add option to attribute

```
public function add($attributeCode, $option);
```

3) Delete option from attribute

```
public function delete($attributeCode, $optionId);
```

Please check you pass correct attribute code name to getItems.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure that the getItems() method will return nothing. The interface passes no attributes whatsoever.

Comment: Also their docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html is saying that eav attributes are cached now, I have to read into that.

Comment: Let me check....@WalterWoshid